# Unable to get geometry from WFS

Tags: geometry, wfs

I have tried to add buildings from WFS layer. https://kartat.espoo.fi/teklaogcweb/wfs.ashx (building layer is GIS:Rakennukset)

Geometry never shows up. However, map extent and data in attribute tables seems to be correct. Also, QGIS doesn't give any error message.

I have been so far able to track down that WFS layer contains different geometry types which seems to be problem for QGIS. I tried to save as GML and then select only polygons, but geometry still doesn't exist (extent and attributes are still fine).

Any tricks/tips?

Comment: What QGIS version are you using? The buildings in the layer you specified work fine for me and are displayed with the default settings.

Comment: I use QGIS3 (3.0.0) and tried 2.18.14 too. OS X 10.12.6

Comment: I also tried to edit geometry. I'm not sure whether visible elements are corners or center points but they disappear when I try to move them. No polygons are shown.

Comment: Then the only problem I can think of is a projection issue. Try loading the layer in a new QGIS session (Vector->Add Layer ->Add WFS Layer from Server), and leaving the default settings for the WFS, with the CRS being 4326 (even though not ideal for this purpose).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

version 2.14 support is ok.
Version 2.18 requires following service URL: https://kartat.espoo.fi/teklaogcweb/wfs.ashx?OUTPUTFORMAT=GML2

Data format have been recently modified to single geometrytype. 
Older multigeometrytype have been a problem for QGis.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I wasn't aware of this change between versions.